# Deleting entry of GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage, delete

I created a GeoPackagein QGIS 3.18 that contains different entries (layers).

How can I delete just on entry of this GeoPackage?

Answer (score 13):

In the browser panel, browse to the Geopackage and expand it. Right click the layer you want to delete and select `Delete layer`.

[image]

Comment: Actually even better than using DB Manager. The Browser-Way offers a little more options like removing single fields or exporting the file as a new one.

Comment: Didn't think about the DB manger , so learned something too :-)

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Markus, accept the answer with the checkbox

Comment: Any idea about how to delete a raster layer from a Geopackage? The browser panel or DB Manager aren't working.

Answer (score 5):

Open `Database` -> `DB Manager`

Then create a connection to your desired Geopackage file by right clicking on `Geopackage` -> `New Connection`

Now you can see the layers. Right click the one you want to delete, and press delete.

[image]

Comment: But don't be surprised if it doesn't work. It seems to be easier to add them than remove them in 3.18 on Mac.

Comment: @wingnut no issues here on 3.18 windows version.

Comment: I tried about ten times, but layers refused to delete. Restarting didn't help. I eventually tried to do it with SQLITE, but it corrupted the GPKG. Fortunately, I had a backup. Otherwise, GPKG is nice to store the project and its layers in a single file. I would again only do it at the end of the project so I don't have to delete anything.

Comment: hm, cant test on a mac.. only reason I can think of that the file/layer might be in use at that time? Anyway, consider making a report at QGIS issues site if that persists.

Comment: I created the GPKG on Windows and moved it to the Mac. It read it OK, just couldn't delete any layers. Deleting the lock file didn't help either. Next time I try, I'll submit something if necessary.